# SSO/SAML trace on Android/iOS

Tags: android, ios, saml, adfs

I am trying to resolve some issues with adfs that only occur via access on mobile devices. How can I run a SAML trace on either iOS or Android?

Comment: Have you tried using the emulators? There is also the remote chrome debugging... https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: The emulators won't work because they are using the same DNS as the ADFS server. The chrome debugging looks promising thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the chrome debugging I mentioned before... I'm a big fan of Fiddler... http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

There are instructions for proxying iOS and Android... http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler

Make sure that you turn on https decryption.